# Device got stolen. How to see its activities using my computer?

Tags: lost-phone, xiaomi-redmi-note-4g

I have 2 mobile devices using the same Gmail account. One of them got stolen. The thief has used my Gmail account and also search.

How can I see the browsing history of the stolen mobile? I already searched in Google activity, and it shows activity for the device I still have. How to find the activity of the stolen device in my Google account? And how to trace the stolen mobile's IMEI and find out which person has it?

Comment: Please specify what you mean by "its activities".

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your goal is finding out where is your phone, there are multiple scenarios. I will cover two of them:

- If you can find the mobile phone on "Your Devices" section ([find it here](https://myaccount.google.com/device-activity)), access it and press "More details" so that you can find the IP address. With the IP address one can find the location, bu using, for example, [WHOIS IP Lookup Tool](https://www.ultratools.com/tools/ipWhoisLookup).
- If you were using "Find My Device" ([with all the musts](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6160491)), access the [Find your phone](https://myaccount.google.com/find-your-phone) section.

---

If you can't find your phone, report the situation to the police and hopefully they will be able to help you.

Then, consider [changing your Google Account password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/7177579#google_password).

Answer (score 0):

All you do is go to devices under google+ and search the history of that device you're looking for. If it's still attached and being used then you know you can locate it from the find my phone app >>IF << your location is turned on on the device. You can also wipe it and make it ring really loud Bob stop for 5 minutes when you get close to it making it easier to find or whenever.